# WCF javascript call cross domain

Tags: javascript, wcf

I am new to javascript and I have a problem that is giving me hard times.

I want to put in a page a tracking javascript. This script will call a wcf service to track client browser information, page visited and timestamp. The problem is that I get: "405 Method Not Allowed" error on javascript call. The service will be on another domain. Now I test this on localhost. The service is working fine because I can call it from a new page in browser. Did you experienced the same problem? How can I fix this?

My javascript code is:

Wcf service code:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "CustomersAssistantService", Namespace = "CustomersAssistantService")]
public interface ICustomersAssistantService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    string DoWork();

    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    string Sum(int n1, int n2);
}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class CustomersAssistantService : ICustomersAssistantService
{
    public string DoWork()
    {
        return "work done";
    }

    public string Sum(int n1, int n2)
    {
        return (n1 + n2).ToString();
    }
}
```

Javascript call:

```
function CallWcf1(){
        var _I = this;
        var url = "http://localhost:58399/CustomersAssistantService.svc/customersAssistantService/";        

            var methodUrl = _I.serviceUrl + 'dowork';

             $.ajax( {
                        url: methodUrl,
                        data: '',
                        type: "GET",
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        timeout: 10000,
                        dataType: "text",  // not "json" we'll parse
                        success: 
                        function(res) 
                        {                                    
                            if (!callback) return;
                            // *** Use json library so we can fix up MS AJAX dates
                            var result = JSON2.parse(res);
                            // *** Bare message IS result
                            if (bare)
                            { callback(result); return; }
                            // *** Wrapped message contains top level object node
                            // *** strip it off
                            for(var property in result)
                            {
                                callback( result[property] );
                                break;
                            }                    
                        },
                        error:  
                        function(xhr)
                        {
                            if (!error) return;
                            if (xhr.responseText)
                            {
                                var err = JSON2.parse(xhr.responseText);
                                if (err)
                                    error(err); 
                                else    
                                    error( { Message: "Unknown server error." })
                            }
                            return;
                        }
                    });   
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot, Radu D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into [the Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Ajax requests are limited to talking to the *same origin*; cross-domain requests will typically be denied.

Depending on your needs, there are various approaches:

- If your users will be using only quite modern browsers (so, not IE7), you could implement [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) on your server. This is a standard from the W3C that allows a server to open up access to its resources cross-origin, but it's only supported in modern browsers. (And on IE, it's supported, but not via the usual `XMLHttpRequest` object; instead, you have to use the `XDomainRequest` object.)
- You could implement a [JSON-P interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP).
- If all you want to do is send a notification to the other domain, you can just load a resource from it (an `img`, a `script`, whatever) by adding those elements with the relevant `src` attribute; this means, though, that you're limited to using the `GET` method which is supposed to be for idempotent resources.

Comment: do you know how Google tracking code works? I assume that it does the call to a service for tracking information.

Comment: @Radu: I just added some bullet points for how you might work with this as you commented. Google uses the third one (a `script` element).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, request for WCF must use the POST method, so change to:

```
type: "POST",
```

In the AJAX call.

Comment: I tried also with post, I have two test methods one is get and one is post ... but I think that there is a problem with cross domain calls.